# Getting a SEEK rather than SCAN on an Aggregate

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

This is doing my headin, but I'm stuck on trying to get an Index Seek on the MAX aggregate within this query.

Here is the [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hy3JxRw-z) - and I'm wondering what I'm missing here, as currently as the query takes 3/4 seconds to complete which is too slow. I've indexed on StartDate, ClientID with no luck.

```
CREATE TABLE #SearchWords
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    Word NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #SearchWords
(
    Word
)
SELECT 
    value 
FROM 
    STRING_SPLIT(@SearchWords, ' ')  
WHERE 
    TRIM(value) <> '' 

SELECT
    C.ClientID, 
    C.FirstName,
    C.LastName,
    C.FullName, 
    C.DateOfBirth,
    G.GenderName, 
    G.GenderIcon, 
    C.VerificationCode,
    MAX(V.StartDate) as LastVisitDate
FROM 
    Client C
LEFT JOIN Visit V on 
    C.ClientID = V.ClientID
INNER JOIN LookUp.Gender G on
    C.GenderID = G.GenderID
WHERE
    (
        EXISTS( -- if we have words
                SELECT *
                FROM #SearchWords s
                WHERE (c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
                    OR (c.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
                    OR (c.VerificationCode LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
            )
        OR
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #SearchWords)=0 -- if we haven't any words
    )
    AND DateOfBirth BETWEEN ISNULL(@LowerDate,DateOfBirth) AND ISNULL(@UpperDate,DateOfBirth)
GROUP BY
    C.ClientID, 
    C.FirstName,
    C.LastName,
    C.FullName, 
    C.DateOfBirth,
    G.GenderName, 
    G.GenderIcon, 
    C.VerificationCode
```

Comment: Think I'd need some example data to dig into this...  that said I can recommend a couple of improvements. Firstly; do you need all matches to the Visit table or just after the most recent (hence the MAX)? I'd also change your `OR (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #SearchWords)=0` to `NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #SearchWords)`. Or better yet, grab the  `@@ROWCOUNT` value from your insert into `#SearchWords` and test that.

Comment: Thanks @KentChenery, how can I share sample data through stackexchange?

Comment: Couple of (popular ways) are: 1) Add some tables in your description with values...essentially formatted text 2) Create scripts in your question that populate exampes or 3) use http://dbfiddle.uk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your index to have ClientID as the leading key.  E.g.:

`CREATE INDEX IX_Visit_ClientID_StartDate ON Visit(ClientID, StartDate)`

This is because you need to join on ClientID before finding the most recent StartDate. Therefore ClientID needs to appear first.

Along with that index change... Since you only want to find the *most recent* `Visit.StartDate` you can change your `LEFT JOIN Visit` to an `OUTER APPLY` that gets the most recent date.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #SearchWords
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    Word NVARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @SearchWordCount INTEGER;

INSERT INTO #SearchWords
(
    Word
)
SELECT 
    value 
FROM 
    STRING_SPLIT(@SearchWords, ' ')  
WHERE 
    TRIM(value) <> ''

SELECT @SearchWordCount = @@ROWCOUNT;

SELECT
    C.ClientID, 
    C.FirstName,
    C.LastName,
    C.FullName, 
    C.DateOfBirth,
    G.GenderName, 
    G.GenderIcon, 
    C.VerificationCode,
    V.LastVisitDate
FROM 
    Client C
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT MAX(StartDate) AS LastVisitDate
    FROM Visit AS V
    WHERE C.ClientID = V.ClientID
) AS V
INNER JOIN LookUp.Gender G on
    C.GenderID = G.GenderID
WHERE
    (
        EXISTS( -- if we have words
                SELECT *
                FROM #SearchWords s
                WHERE (c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
                    OR (c.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
                    OR (c.VerificationCode LIKE CONCAT('%',s.Word,'%'))
            )
        OR @SearchWordCount = 0
    )
    AND DateOfBirth BETWEEN ISNULL(@LowerDate,DateOfBirth) AND ISNULL(@UpperDate,DateOfBirth)
GROUP BY
    C.ClientID, 
    C.FirstName,
    C.LastName,
    C.FullName, 
    C.DateOfBirth,
    G.GenderName, 
    G.GenderIcon, 
    C.VerificationCode
```

> **Note:**
>
> I've also made the `@@ROWCOUNT` improvement I suggested in my comment.

The `GROUP BY` is almost certainly unnecessary now too.  Remove it if it is.

Off Topic:

One final last comment which is technically unrelated to your question. You seem to be doing something that Full Text Searching may be a better solution for.

Comment: Thanks very much Kent. That's a big improvement and getting a much better plan now - https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyPwaAvbM

Comment: If this solves your issue, please mark as the answer.

Comment: Also I think you missed the `SELECT @SearchWordCount = @@ROWCOUNT;` bit in your query in the "pastetheplan" link/example.

Comment: I think that might be a bug with Brent's script because it's in there. But thanks.

Comment: @James If you think you've found a bug, can you shoot an email to the help account about it? We'd like to get it fixed. Thanks!